# How do I draw a shape with a hole in it?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

How do I draw a blue square with a transparent circular hole in the middle, as shown below, using Delphi and Firemonkey?

I want to draw something like this:

[image: transparent circle on blue surface]

But I can't find a way to make the circle transparent :(

Comment: 3 Steps: Draw the square with no fill, draw the circle with no fill, and then use flood fill between the regions.

Comment: @JerryDodge ... I m on firemonkey :( How to use flood fill between the regions ?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with a Firemonkey canvas, but I'm sure it has a Flood Fill capability, such as VCL has. It's essentially the same thing as using the "paint bucket" in image editors. Provide a color and a point within that area.

Comment: @Jerry, clipping canvas region might be a better option, I'd say.

Comment: @Victoria Indeed. I do agree that there are always two ways to go about anything: The easy way, or the right way. Of course, it always depends on the end usage, which I don't know much about here. If this were re-drawn many times, then clipping is surely better. But when drawing a single image, it's perfectly acceptable to use flood fill.

Comment: @Jerry, I haven't said there's always two ways to achieve what you want with an graphics API :) (sorry, it was my comment post mistake; I wanted to elaborate).

Comment: @Victoria I didn't mean to insinuate you did, I just agree in general :-)  But that rule does apply everywhere.  I live by that rule. It just depends on which situations call for "easy" and which ones call for "right".

Comment: Flood fill could prove difficult to get right, depending on what's already on the canvas. After all, if the hole needs to be transparent, then there's probably already something there that needs to show through, so flood-filling from any given point will surely miss something in the target region.

Comment: The correct way in FMX would be to make a path (TPathData) and then fill the path. Most drawing functions in FMX (like Canvas.FillRect) actually creates a Path and fills it.

Comment: @JerryDodge: no unfortunately their is no Flood Fill capability under firmonkey :(

Comment: @Victoria: their is a concept of clipping under firmonkey, but it's only applicable to TRectF :( so no way to draw a circle with it ...

Comment: @Hans: yes maybe it's could be possible using the TPathData with DoFillPath ... I think now it's will be the only way! maybe it's also what jerry call flood fill

Comment: "*The correct way in FMX would be to make a path (TPathData) and then fill the path*" - in VCL, a similar solution can be done using regions with [`FilRgn()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162720.aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
var lPath: TPathData;
begin
  lPath := TPathData.Create;
  lPath.AddRectangle(RectF(0,0,100,100), 0,0, []);
  lPath.AddEllipse(RectF(20,20,80,80));
  Canvas.Fill.Color := $FF8080FF;
  Canvas.FillPath(lPath,1);
  lPath.Free;
end;
```

Comment: by the way why lPath and not aPath ? what mean L in lpath ?

Comment: "L" just means local variable while "A" means argument (parameter to a procedure/function)